# Ad hoc build changes documents directory

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, adhoc

I've come up against a confusing issue. I'm using Testflight for ad hoc distribution to test my build with a few testers. My app makes use of the documents directory to store images taken with the camera or from the photo library.

The problem I have is that every time I install an ad hoc build from Testflight, it changes the app id part of the documents directory.

ie

```
/var/mobile/Applications/{APPID}/Documents/
```

is different after installing a new ad hoc build. It also changes if I reinstall the same build from Testflight. It was my understanding that this should be consistent - is this not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer does not have control over what appid is used when the app is installed, so you should never trust it to be consistent.  Instead ask the default file manager for the document directory on the fly:

```
NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Comment: I was doing something similar to store the images in the first place. My mistake was to store the full filepath as an attribute on my Image model in Core Data, so I could load it later. This worked fine during development, but the ad hoc caused the issues. Interesting to know, I've rewritten it now.

Comment: Im just having this issue, i need to create directories in the above but I get an error that its not permitted. Any ideas? sorry im digging this up!

Comment: @burrows111 I'm not having problems with this code. It still works in new projects, supplying a URL for the app's document directory. Your problem is probably elsewhere. I suggest writing a full question that includes your problematical code.